How can i convert factor only column of Likert scale from long to wide using dplyr functions in R?
i have the following data frame in R with 3 factor column with the same levels like this :



A
B
C




1 1-Strongly disagree
5-Strongly agree
1-Strongly disagree


2 3-so-so
5-Strongly agree
2-Disagree


3 4-Agree
2-Disagree
2-Disagree


4 2-Disagree
2-Disagree
5-Strongly agree



and i want to use dplyr functions in order to alter my data frame into like this :



Item
1-Strongly disagree
2-Disagree
3-so-so
4-Agree
5-Strongly agree




A
26.72
21.41
27.45
17.80
6.59


B
25.0
20.2
28.27
18.36
8.0


C
6.3
9.5
28.6
40.35
15.17



where the numbers on the cells are arbitrary.
A = sample(c('1-Strongly disagree','2-Disagree','3-so-so','4-Agree','5-Strongly agree'),1000,replace = TRUE)
B = sample(c('1-Strongly disagree','2-Disagree','3-so-so','4-Agree','5-Strongly agree'),1000,replace = TRUE)
C = sample(c('1-Strongly disagree','2-Disagree','3-so-so','4-Agree','5-Strongly agree'),1000,replace = TRUE)

df = tibble(A,B,C)%>%
  mutate(across(everything(),as.factor));df


library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1234) # for reproducible testing
A = sample(c('1-Strongly disagree','2-Disagree','3-so-so','4-Agree','5-Strongly agree'),1000,replace = TRUE)
B = sample(c('1-Strongly disagree','2-Disagree','3-so-so','4-Agree','5-Strongly agree'),1000,replace = TRUE)
C = sample(c('1-Strongly disagree','2-Disagree','3-so-so','4-Agree','5-Strongly agree'),1000,replace = TRUE)

df = tibble(A,B,C)%>%
  mutate(across(everything(),as.factor));df

df |> 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = "Item") |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_fn = length)

gives
# A tibble: 3 × 6
  Item  `4-Agree` `1-Strongly disagree` `2-Disagree` `5-Strongly agree` `3-so-so`
  <chr>     <int>                 <int>        <int>              <int>     <int>
1 A           194                   194          181                197       234
2 B           193                   195          194                219       199
3 C           201                   195          205                199       200


in Base R: array2DF(structure(lapply(df, table), dim = ncol(df)))
